# С# UserControl в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, usercontrol

Есть такой фрагмент разметки

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:MeanNewPersonControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

где Persons, список объектов с полями ФИО и телефон а разметка controls:MeanNewPersonControl:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 10 0 0">
        <TextBlock Text="Имя и отчество: " Width="100"/>
        <TextBox MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 10 0 0">
        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Телефон :"/>
        <xctk:MaskedTextBox Mask="+7(000)-000-00-00" MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding Phone}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Собственно сам вопрос, как связать каждый объект из Persons с MeanNewPersonControl?

Comment: DependencyProperty? `<controls:MeanNewPersonControl  Name = "{Binding Name}"/>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956767/binding-to-custom-dependency-property-again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У DataTemplate есть DataType, в котором можно указать ваш класс с информацией о Person. В итоге что-то такое должно у вас получиться:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonDataTemplate" DataType="YouPersonView">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 10 0 0">
            <TextBlock Text="Имя и отчество: " Width="100"/>
            <TextBox MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 10 0 0">
            <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Телефон :"/>
            <xctk:MaskedTextBox Mask="+7(000)-000-00-00" MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding Phone}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonDataTemplate}"/>
```

Если хотите именно свой контрол использовать (хотя, если это UserControl в котором только StackPanels, то лучше использовать DataTemplate для персона, ну или отдельный Control со своим стилем. И вместо 3 StackPanel использовать 1 Grid с 2мя строчками и 2мя столбцами), то вроде бы достаточно указать DataContext:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <controls:MeanNewPersonControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```